# Configuration parameters in file or DB?

Tags: language-agnostic, configuration

What will be best practice for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configuration in a File or a Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487778/configuration-in-a-file-or-a-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it depends a lot on what you are going to use it for, how often it's going to be changed, etc. For the most part I keep configuration parameters that are unlikely to change in a file (ie: db connection parameters themselves)